# How to navigate to particular tab of <p:tabView> from JavaScript function

Tags: jsf, primefaces, navigation, tabview

I have a tab in my XHTML page which looks like below code

```
<p:tabView widgetVar="tabviewbar">
    <p:tab  id="livetracking_tab">
        // action
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

I have a JavaScript function in which I have html embedded to a string. I should redirect to `livetracking_tab` in `myxhtml` page.

```
<a href='#tabView:livetracking_tab'>Navigate to livetracking tab</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

From `JavaScript` you can switch tabs.

```
PF('tabviewbar').select(0);
```

As parameter you can pass the tab index.

Comment: This is working but it is navigating back to the earlier page immediately.

Comment: Can you please describe the problem more detailed or show some more code?

Answer (score 0):

From JavaScript using jQuery, the below code worked

```
$('#tabView ul li a[href="#tabView\\:livetracking_tab"]').click();
```